# Android HtmlGet trouble

Tags: android

I want to get source of webpage. And for now only display.
I can't compile this code succesfuly. Eclipse saying  Unhandled declaration type IOExeption. When i add "throws declaration" still have some problems. I'm sorry for my english. Thanks for answers.

```
package com.html;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
// More and more import
import android.widget.TextView;


public class GetHtmlActivity extends Activity
{
    String html;

    public String HtmlGet(String url) throws IOException
    {
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    str.append(line);
                }
            in.close();
            return str.toString();
    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle Spusteni) 
    {
        super.onCreate(Spusteni);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        HtmlGet("***");

        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText(html);
        setContentView(tv);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to catch the exception.

```
try {
    HtmlGet("***");
} catch (IOException e) {
    // do something in case of error
}
```

Comment: When I do this only one thing what I get is commands of 
 catch(IOExeption e)